About "source/sink current on FB line" in IP2701 datasheet
There is a part I don't understand while reading the IP2701 dataset.
[When fast charging client-side device connected, IP2701 auto-detect the type of charging standard and analysis the power requirements, source/sink current on FB line to grant the request voltage.]
This is part of the IP2701 datasheet.
I don't understand what source/sink current on FB line is.

So, is the "source/sink current on FB line" Vfb/R2?
For example, as a regulator with FB pin, I use TL431.
Then, Vfb is Vref of TL431 so it is almost 2.5V.
Then, source/sink current on FB line is Vref/100k = 25uA?


Rohat Kılıç points straight at what you need to understand. But is it enough exposition? Do take a look at his link. Do you find it all sufficient? Or not?

data sheet

To adjust a regulator's output voltage externally, you can inject or steal current to/from the FB node of the regulator using an external voltage source. See my answer here for how the mechanism works.
What the IP2701 does is exactly the same thing.
Its FB pin is connected to the regulator's FB pin. And to adjust the regulator's output voltage for fast charging, IP2701 injects (source) or steals (sink) current to/from that node.
